# What are the differences amongst the distinct postgresql query execution functions?

Tags: php, postgresql

It is observed that SQL statements can be executed using methods pg_query(), pg_prepare(), pg_query_params(), pg_execute().

Please guide me when to use which method.

Comment: documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/pgtcl-pgexecute.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to execute a single database operation with manually escaped/prepared variables or just literals and get returned values: `pg_query`, when you want a reusable statement which is executed often with different variables' values + optimized by the driver go for `pg_prepare` together with `pg_execute` (`pg_execute` runs the query prepared by `pg_prepare` with actual variables' values), to execute and return values of a single query with variables escaped/prepared by the driver you have `pg_query_params`